# How can I protect .sql file from App_Data folder on web site project VS 10 (published version)?

Tags: c#, sql-server, visual-studio-2010

For my web site project (VS10 and SQL 2008R2) I read sql file from APP_Data but when I publish and deploy on client side the .sql files are insecure. How can I lock or hide from clients?

Answer (score 0):

have  a look at the attached image:
on the IIS Web Settings:
just add is to the hidden segments / File Extentions

[image]